# Real - time points plotting using opengl VC++

Tags: opengl, visual-c++, glut, freeglut, glu

I need suggestion on how to plot points real-time. Using OpenGL 
Right now what am doing is loading the desired data from a csv to an array and plotting the points from there. This is working fine.

What I intend to do is, load such multiple csv's one by one at regular intervals of time, so that i can create a animation kind of output. I can do this but once the program plots the point by entering `glutMainLoop();`, it never gets out without closing opengl window. I want to load the 1st csv, show it in OpenGL window, then load the next csv and show the new set of points and so on.

If its difficult to comprehend, just see the image below

[image]

Just consider the red and blue points.Consider them as not actually moving but being plotted from an external data with each new postions loaded from the csv file. Hope its clear

Comment: *"once the program plots the point by entering glutMainLoop();, it never gets out without closing opengl window."* - [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php) extends glut by `glutLeaveMainLoop` and `glutMainLoopEvent`.

Comment: Yes, I have used `glutMainLoopEvent` but it seems to be hampering with my `glutMotionFunc`. With `glutMainLoop()`, I can click and drag the scene. With loop event, no drag/pan is happening. I was keeping glutMainLoopEvent as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] once the program plots the point by entering glutMainLoop();, it never gets out without closing opengl window.

[freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php) extends glut by `glutLeaveMainLoop` and `glutMainLoopEvent`.

e.g.:

```cpp
bool condtion = true;
while (condtion)
{
    glutMainLoopEvent(); // handle the main loop once
    glutPostRedisplay(); // cause `display` to be called in `glutMainLoopEvent`

    condtion = ...;
}
```

---

Another option would be to use [`glutIdleFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node63.html) to do additional stuff. So it is not necessary to leave the glut main loop at all..

Comment: Thanks, using `glutPostRedisplay();` allowed me to use `glutMainLoopEvent` without losing my current settings.